# magento extension install issue

Tags: php, magento

i have download a extension from github

https://github.com/codingbasicsnet/AMP-Magento-Extension

But when i start install it gives me error

```
CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
Invalid package name, allowed: [a-zA-Z0-9_-] chars
Invalid version should be like: x.x.x
Invalid stability
Invalid date should be YYYY-DD-MM
Invalid channel URL
Empty authors section
Empty package contents section
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think you are installing the extension through connect manager in magento1. If you need to install the extension through connect manager then you need package.xml on your extension root directory which defines the package name etc.

You can install the same extension by placing the folder and files to respective locations.

Hope this help!